# JQuery TypeWatch Functionality in Delphi

Tags: jquery, delphi, typewatch

TypeWatch is a JQuery plugin that monitors the time between key strokes in a text input box.

It allows for features like refreshing of search results as a user types their search terms, as demonstrated in the 'Users' page in Stack Overflow.

If you are typing in the name of a user you wish to seach for and pause typing for half a second the search result for what you have already entered will appear.

Does anyone have any examples or info on how you could monitor an textbox in delphi in a similar manner, as the user is typing trigger another event if this have stopped typing for a certain period of time, say half a second.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the idea behind the AutoComplete feature of the regular ComboBox.
Or implement a Timer that is reset to 0 at each Keypress in your Edit, and fires its onTimer event handler when it reaches the delay you specified (i.e. after no key entry for this interval of time).
I'm pretty sure there are free components available that implement this...